# Does the set {0,1} form a field if we define 1+1=0?

Tags: linear-algebra

A field should have the property of additive inverse but the set {0,1} forms a field if we define 0+0=0, 1+1=0, 1+0=1, 0.1=0, 0.0=0, 1.1=1 although it does not have additive inverse property. That is, for 1 in the set, there is not -1. How does it form a field?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Well, it does have $-1$, just in a hidden form. Look at $1+1=0$, the formula tells you that the additive inverse of $1$ is itself, i.e. $-1=1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *do* have an element $a$ such that $1+a=0$. That element is $1$. In other words, $-1=1$. And while $-1=1$ makes it behave in weird and unexpected ways at times, what you have is indeed a field.

Comment: Many of the weird and unexpected behaviours of the field with two elements just don't happen with any other prime-order finite field. This has led mathematicians to conclude that 2 is indeed the oddest prime.

Answer (score 1):

The given set and binary operations *do* form a field; $-1=1$ here. This is $\mathbb F_2$, the finite field on $2$ elements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $1$ *has* an additive inverse. It is $1$ itself, since $1+1=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You defined $1+1=0$ where the additive group here is $(\{0,1\},+,0)$. So the inverse of the element $1$ is $1$ in this case.